# How can I insert an image content into "content" property in CSS?

Tags: css

I am seeing `.ss-phone:before, .ss-phone.right:after { content: ''; }` in the css file. I like to insert my own image in, especially some of them with a box and a question mark.

I tried to see the real content within the "content" property using the javascript, but it produces an empty box.

Comment: You can have an image as the content in a pseudo element - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content which shows how to do it with a url. However. the example you gave looks more like an icon/character. If you can expand on what 'a box and a question mark' means (sounds like a placeholder for an image that isn't there) then we could help more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry for not clarifying the question. For whatever reason, some of the icons within the "content" property show up, such as the phone icon in the example; some of them don't, only with a question mark within the box. I wonder how those strange contents within the "content" property are produced, so that I can produce my own, such as a facebook icon.

Comment: As you can see by many of the comments, your question is not clear. Please edit your question to make it clearer. You have replied to some of the comments to give additional detail; you need to now edit your question to add that detail to the question itself. Once your question becomes clear, then you'll most likely get a useful answer very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The "content" property in CSS is used to insert content before or after an element. However, it is not possible to directly access the content of the pseudo-elements like ::before and ::after using JavaScript. These pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM, so they cannot be accessed or modified using JavaScript.

If you want to insert your own image with a box and a question mark, you can create a new class or modify the existing one in the CSS file. Instead of using the "content" property, you can use background-image or background property to set your desired image as the background of the element.

For example, you can create a new CSS class like this:

```
.my-custom-image {
  background-image: url('path/to/your/image.png');
  /* additional styles for the box and question mark */
}
```

Then, you can apply this class to the desired element in your HTML markup:

```
<div class="my-custom-image"></div>
```

This will set the background image of the element to your desired image, along with any additional styles you specify for the box and question mark.

Comment: I actually did that before asking the question. It's not what I want. The problem is that when hovering the image, you will have to produce another image with a different color. But with the "content: '[?]'", you don't have to, you only need to add a font-color for :before and :after. Plus, the hovering effect is much more smooth.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to achieve a smooth hovering effect and change the color of the image when hovering, you can use CSS transitions and pseudo-elements. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<span class="ss-phone"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.ss-phone {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url('path/to/your/image.png');
  background-size: cover;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.ss-phone:before,
.ss-phone:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ss-phone:before {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.ss-phone:after {
  content: '?';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.ss-phone:hover {
  background-color: #yourDesiredColor;
}

.ss-phone:hover:before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

In this example, we are using the  `:before`  and  `:after`  pseudo-elements to create the box and the question mark. The  `transition`  property is used to create a smooth color transition when hovering. You can modify the  `background-color`  values to match your desired colors.
I hope this solution meets your requirements. Let me know if you need any further assistance!